# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'evaluate_features'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run the code below in google colab but I am getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'evaluate_features'`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pickle
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

from evaluate_features import get_features, linear_classifier, tSNE_vis
```

I Was looking around for solutions and found situations referencing just `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'evaluate'`. I tried the solutions for these problems by pip install evaluate thinking that maybe the two modules were one in the same (or equivalent). Still I have the same problem.

EDIT: Provided a requested image.
[image: Image showing evaluate_features file]

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure that module `evaluate_features` is within your colab file workspace.

Once done, it appears that colab deals with module imports quite nicely:

[image: Colab screencap]

My minimal sample code is:

```py
# notebook
from evaluate_features import hello

hello()
```

And then:

```py
# evaluate_features.py
def hello() -> str:
  return "hello, world!"
```

If this doesn't work, please update your question with a similar screencap of your environment.

If `evaluate_features` is an external package, please provide a pypi link.

Comment: So I see from your answer that the evaluate_features is a file included in the files and not a package to be installed with pip. However as shown in the edited question above the file does exist in the folder. Is there a formatting problem?

Comment: In order to import `evaluate_features`, you will need to `cd` into the directory `SimCLRv1-keras-tensorflow` as shown by the other answer. Python cannot find modules in other directories unless you point it to them.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search on Google, it appears you want to use the code from the [third notebook](https://github.com/mwdhont/SimCLRv1-keras-tensorflow/blob/master/2_model_SimCLR.ipynb) of [this repository](https://github.com/mwdhont/SimCLRv1-keras-tensorflow).

Did you miss the first instructions?

```
# 1. Clone the repository
!git clone https://github.com/mwdhont/SimCLRv1-keras-tensorflow.git

# 2. Go to the folder
%cd SimCLRv1-keras-tensorflow/

# 3. Import modules
import numpy as np
import pickle
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16 

from evaluate_features import get_features, linear_classifier, tSNE_vis
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Note**: this repository is 4 years old, there is probably some code that no longer works because of Tensorflow and Pandas versions.

Comment: I did use the first two lines of code. A hiccup I had run in those there was the different required versions for different modules in the required.txt folder either not currently existing or requiring different versions of pip and/or python to function correctly. I ended up just trying to install all the newest versions of the modules which got me to where I am now.